# ASP.net Core can not create new view from controller. There was an error running the selected code generator:'Scaffolding failed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

[Error while creating new view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtJTd.png)

2 days ago I was able to create new views with no problems, now before and after VS  v17.3.3 -> v17.3.4 and packages 6.0.8 -> 6.0.9 updates i'm getting this error 'There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Scaffolding failed. Could not load information for project [.csproj File Location]'
I have updated all packages to latest fixed versions.
I have deleted all files within ComponentModelCache folder.

Comment: Try updating dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator to latest stable using "dotnet tool update -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator"

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on VS 2022. So far nothing worked.